# Facebook get my events

Tags: php, events, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to get my facebook events to which I was invited (reply and not reply) to store them into my personal DB.

I've create a facebook application and I'm using facebook API with the PHP SDK.

How can i do it?

Comment: Just query them with Graph https://graph.facebook.com/me/events

Answer (score 0):

Events can be accessed by the graph api with urls like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/events?access_token=<user_access_token>
```

To make this work, you will have to ask for the `user_events` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). More on the Event object in graph api [in the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).